# How to create an XML document from a .NET object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have the following variable that accepts a file name:

```
var xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFileName) { WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None };
var xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.Load(xtr);
```

I would like to change it so that I can pass in an object. I don't want to have to serialize the object to file first.

Is this possible?

Update:

My original intentions were to take an xml document, merge some xslt (stored in a file), then output and return html... like this:

```
public string TransformXml(string xmlFileName, string xslFileName)
{
     var xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFileName) { WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None };
     var xd = new XmlDocument();
     xd.Load(xtr);

     var xslt = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
     xslt.Load(xslFileName);
     var stm = new MemoryStream();
     xslt.Transform(xd, null, stm);
     stm.Position = 1;
     var sr = new StreamReader(stm);
     xtr.Close();
     return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

In the above code I am reading in the xml from a file. Now what I would like to do is just work with the object, before it was serialized to the file.

So let me illustrate my problem using code

```
public string TransformXMLFromObject(myObjType myobj , string xsltFileName)
{
     // Notice the xslt stays the same.
     // Its in these next few lines that I can't figure out how to load the xml document (xd) from an object, and not from a file....

     var xtr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFileName) { WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None };
     var xd = new XmlDocument();
     xd.Load(xtr);
}
```

Comment: I don't follow what you are wanting to do, can you post a better example?

Comment: change *what* so that you can pass in an object?  The XmlTextReader?  you want to pass an object to the XmlTextReader?  And what do you expect to get *out* ?

Comment: @JL: you should not be using `new XmlTextReader()`. You should be using `XmlReader.Create()` instead.

Comment: @Cheeso, I want to load xd (the XMLDocument) from an object, not from file, the XMLTextReader is not important to me.

Comment: i guess he wants some serialization technology which creates an object from existing XML. Or I'm getting it wrong and he wants to modify the XML right after loading it or just create the XmlDocument-Object right from XmL. You may want to use the XmlDocument.LoadXml method if this is the case

Comment: @John, any reason why new XMLTestReader is bad?

Comment: @JL: take it easy. I don't live on SO. See the comment by Darin, below.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You want to turn an arbitrary .NET object into a serialized XML string? Nothing simpler than that!! :-)

```
public string SerializeToXml(object input)
{
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType(), "http://schemas.yournamespace.com");
   string result = string.Empty;

   using(MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
   {
     ser.Serialize(memStm, input);

     memStm.Position = 0;
     result = new StreamReader(memStm).ReadToEnd();
   } 

   return result;
}
```

That should to it :-) Of course you might want to make the default XML namespace configurable as a parameter, too.

Or do you want to be able to create an XmlDocument on top of an existing object?

```
public XmlDocument SerializeToXmlDocument(object input)
{
   XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(input.GetType(), "http://schemas.yournamespace.com");

   XmlDocument xd = null;

   using(MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
   {
     ser.Serialize(memStm, input);

     memStm.Position = 0;

     XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
     settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;

     using(var xtr = XmlReader.Create(memStm, settings))
     {  
        xd = new XmlDocument();
        xd.Load(xtr);
     }
   }

   return xd;
}
```

Comment: @marc_s: ick! No `using` blocks! `new XmlTextReader()`! -1!

Comment: @John: I was just fixing the `new XmlTextReader()`.... you're too quick to downvote......

Comment: @John: but explain to me in simple and easy to understand words the benefit of `XmlReader.Create()` vs. `new XmlTextReader()` - nobody has made a compelling point so far.....

Comment: @marc_s: why not use StringWriter and StringReader, rather than MemoryStream and StreamReader ? I think it would make more sense here ;). Regarding XmlReader.Create, it's just a MS recommendation... I don't know the exact reason

Comment: @Thomas: why?? What do you think would be the benefit of StringWriter vs. MemoryStream? Just curious.... you might be totally right, I've never considered using a StringWriter here.....

Comment: @marc_s, re: `XmlReader.Create()` vs `new XmlTextReader()`, it's a basic factory vs constructor.  Maybe it's a good topic for your own question, heh heh. @Every one else: the critics are out!

Comment: @marc_s, quote from the doc: `Although the Microsoft .NET Framework includes concrete implementations of the XmlReader class, such as the XmlTextReader, XmlNodeReader, and the XmlValidatingReader classes, in the .NET Framework version 2.0, we recommend that you create XmlReader instances using the Create method` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9khb6435.aspx). I guess the only compelling reason might be that if in .NET 7.9 they introduce the `HyperXmlReader` class you won't need to change your code to benefit from it :-)

Comment: @marc_s: in your second piece of code, it doesn't change anything. But in the first one, you're returning a string, so using a MemoryStream and then reading it with a StreamReader to obtain a string seems a bit overcomplicated... with a StringWriter, you get a string directly

Comment: @marc_s: It means you can be returned whatever `XmlReader` derivative may be appropriate, based on the `XmlReaderSettings`.

Comment: @John, @Thomas: thanks for your explanations and inputs! Highly appreciated - you learn something new (and useful) every day....

Answer (score 31):

You can serialize directly into the `XmlDocument`:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
using (XmlWriter w = nav.AppendChild())
{
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyType));
    ser.Serialize(w, myObject);
}
```

Comment: I think the ser.Serializer doesn't accept the object as a parameter?

Comment: uh, nice... and no intermediate string involved :)

Comment: If I wasn't clear enough, the code above doesn't compile because ser.Serialize has some invalid parameters. Otherwise it looks like an elegant solution.

Comment: @JL: I've been offline. Also, you'll want to use @user to get someone's attention. They'll be notified when you do. I've fixed the typo. The parameters were in the wrong order.

Comment: I did a test with a list of 100 small objects (custom one containing a datetime, a string, a guid and an enum). This method took 2 ms on average while the longer method took on average 170ms to process all 100 items. It's not a proper benchmark, but it gives an idea of the overall effecientness of the two functions.

Comment: But since it's not a proper benchmark, it may give a _false_ idea of the performance.

Comment: @JohnSaunders may I know what advantage this approach has over MemoryStream approach?

Comment: @randomuser: no intermediate Stream or TextReader objects. If you only need those objects to construct the XmlDocument, then why bother with them?

Comment: This should be accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 16):

Expanding on @JohnSaunders solution I wrote the following generic function:

```cs
public static XmlDocument SerializeToXml<T>(
            T source,
            XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = null)
{
    var document = new XmlDocument();
    var navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

    using var writer = navigator.AppendChild();
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.Serialize(writer, source, namespaces);
    
    return document;
}
```