# WCF When responding via Message.CreateMessage tags are swapped

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, ws-security, envelope

I am implementing the IDispatchMessageInspector in the BeforeSendReply method, in which the signed xml is loaded. For clarity, an xml document without a signature.

```
string testXml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\test\\test.xml");
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(testXml));
var message = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version);
reply = message;
```

After receiving the response in SoapUI, the tags are swapped. The upper xml loaded from the file, the lower response in SoapUI This response does not pass validation, by checksum.

Please tell me, is it possible to return the data without changes?

The function for the signature returns a string. Maybe there are other ways to return the answer?

[image]

Comment: Why? [it doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57756005/writing-xml-attributes-and-namespace-declarations-in-a-specific-order#answer-57757267)

Comment: If there are at least some changes in the response, then the hash sum is not valid when validating the signature

Comment: `response string = reply.toString();` - the data is correct here, but the attributes in SoapUI are swapped

Comment: That's a better question, but can you post more information?